# Static method return an object of it's containing class type

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have:

```
class Person
{

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello I am a person");
    }

    public static T GenerateRandomInstance<T>() where T: Person
    {
        var p = new T("hello", 4); // error does not compile
        // rondomize properties
        return p;                
    }
}

class Student : Person
{
    // constructor I call the base class here
    public Student(string name, int age)
        : base(name, age)
    {    
    }

    public override void Speak()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello I am a student");
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that when I do:

```
Student.GenerateRandomInstance();
```

I get a `Person` instead of a `Student`. How can I fix the `GenerateRandomInstance` method so it returns a Student instead of a Person. **Casting a person to student gives me an error**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. A static method cannot be overridden in a child class and there's no way to distinguish between `Student.GenerateRandomInstance` and `Person.GenerateRandomInstance`—in fact they generate exactly the same CIL when compiled.

You could use a generic method instead:

```
public static T GenerateRandomInstance<T>() where T : Person, new
{
    var p = new T();
    // randomize properties
    return p;
}

Person.GenerateRandomInstance<Student>();
```

But this will only work if the type has a parameterless constructor. If you'd like to pass arguments to the constructor, it becomes somewhat more difficult. Assuming you always know what values you want to pass to the constructor you can do this:

```
public static T GenerateRandomInstance<T>() where T : Person
{
    var p = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), "hello", 4);
    // randomize properties
    return p;
}
```

Of course, this too will fail if the specified type does not contain a suitable constructor.

Comment: +1 thanks! person constructor takes 2 arguments though... I should have mention that I did not know you where going to post this nice answer ;)

Comment: @TonoNam are the parameters going to be the same for every sub-type of `Person` or could they be different types?

Comment: I am working on an edit that's going to be there in less than 1 min thanks so much for the help...

Comment: Person requires two arguments that's why I can't use the `new` keyword :(

Comment: p.s.w.g it will be nice I don't have to specify `T` I know that `T` has to be of the parent class type. There is no way I can remove that right? since I cannot use the `this` keyword how can I know the type in order to remove the `<T>` generic parameter.

Comment: @TonoNam Correct. Static methods belong to the type that declared them and have no clue about how they are called. You can write `Student.GenerateRandomInstance` but that's identical to `Person.GenerateRandomInstance`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. `Person` and `Student` each define their own `GenerateRandomInstance` and `RandomizeProperties` methods. `Student` calls `Person`'s `RandomizeProperties` to let the base class randomize the properties that it knows about. `Student` would then only randomize the properties that are introduced by the `Student` class.

NOTE: This problem is often solved by the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design patterns. The solution below is neither of those.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello I am a person");
    }

    public static Person GenerateRandomInstance()
    {
        var o = new Person();
        RandomizeProperties(o);
        return o;
    }

    protected static void RandomizeProperties(Person o)
    {
        // randomize Person properties here
    }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public override void Speak()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello I am a student");
    }

    // note the use of the 'new' keyword
    new public static Student GenerateRandomInstance()
    {
        var o = new Student();
        RandomizeProperties(o);
        return o;
    }

    protected static void RandomizeProperties(Student o)
    {
        Person.RandomizeProperties(o);

        // randomize Student properties here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `GenerateRandomInstance()` method in your Student class. currently the base method in Person is being called.

Comment: You can't override a static method